# Peak element in array Python

Tags: arrays

I was solving this peak element problem from gfg.
The problem goes below:-

Given an array of integers. Find a peak element in it. An array element is a peak if it is NOT smaller than its neighbors. For corner elements, we need to consider only one neighbor.

Example:

Input: array[]= {5, 10, 20, 15}
Output: 20
The element 20 has neighbours 10 and 15,
both of them are less than 20.

I wrote the following code to solve the problem as suggested in gfg itself.

```
def peakoptimized(self,arr,n,low=0,high=0):
    low = low
    high = high
    mid = int(low + high /2)

    if arr[mid -1] <= arr[mid] and arr[mid+1] <= arr[mid]:
        print(arr[mid -1],arr[mid],arr[mid+1])  
        print(mid,arr[mid])             
        return mid
    elif arr[mid -1] > arr[mid]:
        self.peakoptimized(arr,n,low=0,high=mid-1)
    elif arr[mid+1] > arr[mid]:
        self.peakoptimized(arr,n,low=mid+1,high=n-1)
```

**Func calling**

```
a = [3, 20,60,4,70,1, 0]#[1,2,5,4,6,7,3,1]
index = sol.peakoptimized(a,len(a),low=0,high=len(a)-1)
print(index)
```

For this particular input i.e **[3, 20,60,4,70,1, 0]** , it is returning None, i don't understand the reason.
PS:- it is working fine on other i/ps, I have randomly provided this i/p but it's not working.

Can anyone please explain the reason ?. I have also tried debugging the code but couldn't find any explanation for the **None** value.

Answer (score 3):

Below solution might work for all 1-D array

```
def _find_peak(arr):
   length = int(len(arr) / 2)
   if length - 1 > 0 and arr[length] < arr[length - 1]:
       return _find_peak(arr[:length])
   elif length + 1 < len(arr) and arr[length] < arr[length + 1]:
       return _find_peak(arr[length:])
   else:
       return arr[length]
```

**Explanation:**

The `_find_peek` funciton only needs the array for which we need the peak.
So for your given input `[3, 20, 60, 4, 70, 1, 0]` the iterations performed by the functions on the array are

> arr=[3, 20, 60, 4, 70, 1, 0]

> arr=[3, 20, 60]

> arr=[20, 60]

### IF YOU NEED TO KNOW WHAT IS WRONG WITH YOUR CODE THEN

**Problems with your solution:**

Issue 1:

> mid = int(low + high / 2)

It should have been

> mid = int((low + high) / 2) # BODMAS

Issue 2:

The change of high and low on the recursive call is wrong the new high value will be same as previous high value if the next element is greater than the mid element, like

> return peak_optimized(arr, n, low=mid + 1, high=high)

Issue 3:

Recursive call is wrong because for all the re-call (recursive call) you have to put the return statement

```
if arr[mid - 1] <= arr[mid] and arr[mid + 1] <= arr[mid]:
    return mid
elif arr[mid - 1] > arr[mid]:
    return peak_optimized(arr, n, low=low, high=mid - 1)
elif arr[mid + 1] > arr[mid]:
    return peak_optimized(arr, n, low=mid + 1, high=high)
```

**Your fixed solution**

```
def peak_optimized(arr, n, low, high):
    low = low
    high = high
    mid = int((low + high) / 2)

    if arr[mid - 1] <= arr[mid] and arr[mid + 1] <= arr[mid]:
        return arr[mid]
    elif arr[mid - 1] > arr[mid]:
        return peak_optimized(arr, n, low=low, high=mid - 1)
    elif arr[mid + 1] > arr[mid]:
        return peak_optimized(arr, n, low=mid + 1, high=high)
```

Hope this helps!! Please comment if any help needed.